# How to store html structure in variable , jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see the following code

```
<div class="test" style="color:red">1</div>
<div class="test" style="color:blue">2</div>
<div class="test" style="color:green">3</div>
```

I need to save this html structure in javascript variable . So that i used the following code

```
<script>
    $(".test").each(function(){
var otext='<div class="test" style="color:'+$(".test").css("color")+';">'+$(".test").text()+'</div>';
    });
</script>
```

but in otext i got `<div class="test" style="color:redbluegreen">123</div>`.
Actually what wrong in my code ? How to store all html structure and style of class test using jquery?

the desired out put is `var otext =<div class="test" style="color:red">1</div><div class="test" style="color:blue">2</div><div class="test" style="color:green">3</div>;`

UPDATE :

what happen if the html structure is lite this ?

```
<div class="test" style="color:red">1<button clss="test-button" value="remove"/></div>
```

and here i don't want to save this div structure without `<button class="test-button">`.

Comment: first get otext variable out of each function then store using otext += '<...>' inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to iterate and create an array of string using [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property of each element.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var text = $(".test").map(function() {
    return this.outerHTML
  }).get().join('');
  console.log(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="color:red">1</div>
<div class="test" style="color:blue">2</div>
<div class="test" style="color:green">3</div>
```

As per comment

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var text = $(".test").map(function() {
    var elem = $(this).clone();
    elem.find('.test-button').remove();
    return elem.prop("outerHTML").trim();
  }).get().join('');
  console.log(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="color:red">1
  <button class="test-button" value="remove" />
</div>
<div class="test" style="color:blue">2
  <button class="test-button" value="remove" />
</div>
<div class="test" style="color:green">3
  <button class="test-button" value="remove" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you . I just update the question .please look .

Answer (score 3):

In your context the each loop every time the variable has been reassigned and override the values. Assign as global variable and concat it.

And use `$(this)` for getting current object

```js
var otext = '';

$(".test").each(function(){
 otext +='<div class="test" style="color:'+$(this).css("color")+';">'+$(this).text()+'</div>';
});

console.log(otext);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="color:red">1</div>
<div class="test" style="color:blue">2</div>
<div class="test" style="color:green">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var otext = '';
```

in function

```
otext+='<div cl......
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your html inside a div like

```
<div id="mydiv>
    <div class="test" style="color:red">1</div>
   <div class="test" style="color:blue">2</div>
   <div class="test" style="color:green">3</div>
</div>
```

Then use the jquery as

```
var html=$('#mydiv').html();
```